# Install Linux Mint on PC without bootable CD

Tags: windows-xp, multi-boot, linux-mint

Unfortunately my PC's CD drive is not bootable; I have such a mixture of SATA and IDE drives, so until I have more money to redo my controller setup, I can't boot from any cd.

Currently, I have a DVD burned with latest version of Linux Mint, and I have an USB drive with an old version of Mint.

I have a partition ready to install Linx Mint into, but no idea how to install it, since I can only boot to my hard drive.

I am totally unable to boot to CD, so that is definitely out.

My main partition is WinXP Pro SP3.

Is there software I can use to format my Linux partition, so that I can then just copy Mint over to that partition? Or is there a better way to install linux mint? I have to do it within Windows XP, since that's all that I can boot right now.

I have considered Mint4Win, but that doesn't allow a full installation of Linux Mint.

Any ideas?

Comment: Atm, struggling to figure out the linux mint installation wizard. Do i delete an existing partition, that was created for it, so that the install wizard can create the partitions it needs?

Comment: I think so (never used Mint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable USB drive from your Mint DVD.

Comment: If his BIOS is(?) that cluttered, then a USB probably wouldn't work either.

Comment: @ekaj you can usually do a one time boot from a separate BIOS menu (usually F12)

Comment: @Simon, but this would apply to CDs as well, which makes me think that this isn't an option.. It could be, but from the way I understand the question it is not. Pressing 'F12' or whatever may be an option for the answer, since it does not really relate to the BIOS (if that makes sense)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the possibility of booting from USB is independent of the number of the hard drives. He could, also, disconnect the CD drive and then be able to boot from USB.

Comment: I was able to use unetbootin, great idea. I can boot as linux mint, but i have trouble installing it to an existing partition. Should I just delete that partition, and let the install create it's own partition?

Comment: @crosenblum doing that wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You can use unetbootin to run the installer straight up, or a livecd. then use that to install mint. You shouldn't have to muck around with the bios at any point

Comment: i got unetbootin on my usb drive and it worked, and week's later am really enjoying linux, and linux mint. thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you should be able to install Linux Mint on another PC, copy the entire filesystem to removable media, then copy to your partition. (Binary copy as in `dd` - Windows version [here](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd)) With Linux, the filesystem is the entire OS - no Windows registry garbage - so this should work as long as Linux Mint doesn't customize the kernel for detected hardware or something of that sort.

Comment: I don't think this will work because it won't copy the bootloader.  Also, the windows registry is part of the filesystem.